# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteValue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization, nsvalue

This is my dictionary:

```
 { @"RoutePolyline":<__NSArrayM 0x283983750>(<c59272f7 39263940      55a4c2d8 42f65240>),
    @"RideID":6565
};
```

I am sending this dictionary as an argument in my API call.

and my app crashes at this line of code:

```
 NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
```

This is the error it throws:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (NSConcreteValue)'

I know the RoutePolyline parameter is holding a NSValue (it is supposed to be an array of coordinates) and not any object type, but I have tried converting alot, but nothing have worked so far. For example

```
[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:*routeCoordinates]
```

Comment: `NSValue` is not JSON compliant. Send each coordinate as array of Double (`NSNumber`) or alternatively as base64 encoded `Data`

Comment: @vadian Can you suggest some code please. 
Its an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D. I fetch it from mapbox like this: CLLocationCoordinate2D *routeCoordinates = malloc(route.coordinateCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
[route getCoordinates:routeCoordinates]; 
and then add it to array like this: NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new]; [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:*routeCoordinates]];

Comment: That's a C array. Sorry, I'm not familiar with this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through your `NSValue` array and extract `CLLocationCoordinate2D`'s value.

```
for (NSValue *value in coordinates) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    [value getValue:&coordinate];
    NSDictionary *coDic = @{@"latitude" : [NSNumber numberWithDouble: coordinate.latitude],
                            @"longitude": [NSNumber numberWithDouble: coordinate.longitude]};
    [array addObject:coDic];
}
```

Also Check if dictionary is valid JSON before serialize

```
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dic]) {
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
}
```

Comment: but what I want to convert it into a valid JSON. I know it is invalid.

Comment: @Ghazalah What is the type of coordinate? CGPoint?

Comment: its an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D. I fetch it from mapbox like this:  CLLocationCoordinate2D *routeCoordinates = malloc(route.coordinateCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
 [route getCoordinates:routeCoordinates]; and then add it to array like this:  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:*routeCoordinates]];

Comment: @Ghazalah So its of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which is not valid JSON object type, you have to  get its `latitude ` and `longitude `, store it in a dictionary then put it in an array.

Comment: you added one element where as the routeCoordinates is an array. And  the problem is you cannot treat them as normal array as I said the compiler is taking it as NSValue

Comment: @Ghazalah If  `routeCoordinates`  is an array, why are you declaring it as `CLLocationCoordinate2D *routeCoordinates`?

Comment: here is an example of the NSValue Array I am trying to send in the API argument list:  route.coordinates
<Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x600001167380>(
<8bfb8f4c 87263940 55302aa9 13f65240>,
<c5c551b9 89263940 2310afeb 17f65240>,
<57738060 8e263940 cb7d7214 20f65240>,
<68aa27f3 8f263940 ed056685 22f65240>,
<027d224f 92263940 0f5a0f5f 26f65240>,
<06d2c5a6 95263940 6b921ff1 2bf65240>,
<393defc6 82263940 70016894 2ef65240>,
<bd66b96c 74263940 16821c94 30f65240>,
<8b2958e3 6c263940 21fc8ba0 31f65240>
)

Comment: I have an object of type MBRoute that has a property called coordinates. This property is an array of NSValue type of CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates. Its a very tight stuck situation. I need to send this array in the API argument and it seems impossible.

Comment: @Ghazalah I've updated my answer including how to get `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from `NSValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Get coordinates (lat longs) values first and store to an array, you can serialize then, it should not crash. Try by using `NSString` values in api:

```
NSArray *arr = @[ @{@“lat”: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",routeCoordinates.latitude],
                    @“long”:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",routeCoordinates.longitude]
                }];
```